# How do I extract a dictionary from a list which only has that dictionary in it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to make an algorithmic trading program, and

```
open_positions = trader.open_positions
for position in open_positions:
    print(position)
```

outputs two dictionaries (?)

```
{'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 5, 'tradeId': '32572646', 'accountName': '05654022', 'accountId': '5654022', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0.71538, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 1298.32056, 'close': 0.71631, 'visiblePL': 9.3, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': True, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 139.59559, 'time': '10022020065344', 'usedMargin': 2500, 'OpenOrderRequestTXT': 'FXTC', 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0}
{'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 0, 'tradeId': '', 'accountName': '', 'accountId': '', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 1298.32056, 'close': 0, 'visiblePL': 9.3, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': False, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 0, 'time': None, 'usedMargin': 0, 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0, 'isTotal': True}
```

The thing is, when I put the above block of code in my actual program, it falls into a weird loop and never comes out. So, I'm trying to find a way to isolate the real dictionary (the first one) from the list without using a loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

*the list

```
[{'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 5, 'tradeId': '32572646', 'accountName': '05654022', 'accountId': '5654022', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0.71538, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 433.14843, 'close': 0.71569, 'visiblePL': 3.1, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': True, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 139.71652, 'time': '10022020065344', 'usedMargin': 2500, 'OpenOrderRequestTXT': 'FXTC', 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0}, {'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 0, 'tradeId': '', 'accountName': '', 'accountId': '', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 433.14843, 'close': 0, 'visiblePL': 3.1, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': False, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 0, 'time': None, 'usedMargin': 0, 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0, 'isTotal': True}]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if u provide the list.

Comment: If you are only interested in a specific item within a list there is no need to loop through the whole list and get the item from the list. Just access the list referring to the relevant index number of the item you want to access. For example if you are sure that `open_positions` is in fact a list, `open_positions[0]` will access the first item of the list, that should be the dictionary you are trying to isolate.

Comment: did you try slicing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
dict1, dict2 = [{'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 5, 'tradeId': '32572646', 'accountName': '05654022', 'accountId': '5654022', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0.71538, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 433.14843, 'close': 0.71569, 'visiblePL': 3.1, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': True, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 139.71652, 'time': '10022020065344', 'usedMargin': 2500, 'OpenOrderRequestTXT': 'FXTC', 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0}, {'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 0, 'tradeId': '', 'accountName': '', 'accountId': '', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 433.14843, 'close': 0, 'visiblePL': 3.1, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': False, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 0, 'time': None, 'usedMargin': 0, 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0, 'isTotal': True}]
```

dict1 would then give you:

```
{'t': 1,
 'ratePrecision': 5,
 'tradeId': '32572646',
 'accountName': '05654022',
 'accountId': '5654022',
 'roll': 0,
 'com': 0,
 'open': 0.71538,
 'valueDate': '',
 'grossPL': 433.14843,
 'close': 0.71569,
 'visiblePL': 3.1,
 'isDisabled': False,
 'currency': 'AUD/USD',
 'isBuy': True,
 'amountK': 1000,
 'currencyPoint': 139.71652,
 'time': '10022020065344',
 'usedMargin': 2500,
 'OpenOrderRequestTXT': 'FXTC',
 'stop': 0,
 'stopMove': 0,
 'limit': 0}
```

OR you can do something like this:

```
L = [{'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 5, 'tradeId': '32572646', 'accountName': '05654022', 'accountId': '5654022', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0.71538, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 433.14843, 'close': 0.71569, 'visiblePL': 3.1, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': True, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 139.71652, 'time': '10022020065344', 'usedMargin': 2500, 'OpenOrderRequestTXT': 'FXTC', 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0}, {'t': 1, 'ratePrecision': 0, 'tradeId': '', 'accountName': '', 'accountId': '', 'roll': 0, 'com': 0, 'open': 0, 'valueDate': '', 'grossPL': 433.14843, 'close': 0, 'visiblePL': 3.1, 'isDisabled': False, 'currency': 'AUD/USD', 'isBuy': False, 'amountK': 1000, 'currencyPoint': 0, 'time': None, 'usedMargin': 0, 'stop': 0, 'stopMove': 0, 'limit': 0, 'isTotal': True}]
```

L[0]

```
{'t': 1,
     'ratePrecision': 5,
     'tradeId': '32572646',
     'accountName': '05654022',
     'accountId': '5654022',
     'roll': 0,
     'com': 0,
     'open': 0.71538,
     'valueDate': '',
     'grossPL': 433.14843,
     'close': 0.71569,
     'visiblePL': 3.1,
     'isDisabled': False,
     'currency': 'AUD/USD',
     'isBuy': True,
     'amountK': 1000,
     'currencyPoint': 139.71652,
     'time': '10022020065344',
     'usedMargin': 2500,
     'OpenOrderRequestTXT': 'FXTC',
     'stop': 0,
     'stopMove': 0,
     'limit': 0}
```